# how to pass object as params in Router.push() in nextjs and access that object in other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push, next.js, router

`Router.push({pathname: '/card', query:{data: ObjectData}})`

I get query as empty value could not pass object into it

Comment: What is `ObjectData` , can you post code that shows how it's created. Have you tried passing an example object into it, e.g: `{foo:bar}` - Empty value means its initialized but `ObjectData` is not accessible

Answer (score 27):

you can pass your params like this case:

```
router.push({
      pathname: '/card',
      query: { data: JSON.stringify(ObjectData)}
  })
```

and you can get params in card component like this:

```
JSON.parse(props.router.query.data);
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the right answer. If you ever come across with the error `Argument of type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'` just change the argument to `JSON.parse(props.router.query.data as string)`

Answer (score 4):

Ciao, in next.js you can pass query parameters like this:

```
Router.push({
  pathname: '/card',
  query: { name: 'Someone' }
})
```

And you retrieve it this way:

```
this.props.router.query.name
```

Supposing that your `ObjectData` is a JSON object, you could pass it like:

```
Router.push({pathname: '/card', query: ObjectData})
```

Comment: and what if i dont want to pass ObjectData in query and paas as a normal params as a object

Comment: Ciao, I don't think you could do that. I'm reading next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router). As examples show, you ca pass props only using query props.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for me. It says Cannot read property `query` of undefined

I have an object of `userData` which I want to pass from nav component to `userprofilePage`.

So, in nav I write:

```
onClick={() => {
  Router.push({
    pathname: "/userProfilePage",
    query: { data: JSON.stringify(userData) },
  });
}}
```

and to retrieve in `userProfilePage`:

```
const router = useRouter();
const userData = JSON.parse(props.router.query.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

this how you pass object as parameter in nextjs

```
  router.push({
  pathname: "/biodata",
  query: { data: "test" },
  });
```

and if it is a variable e.g id=12346

```
 router.push({
  pathname: "/biodata",
  query: { data: id },
  });
```

and you access that object in other component using these line of code

```
const router = useRouter();
const {
query: { data },
} = router;
```

i.e how to used it in new page   .about page

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
export default function AboutPage() {
const router = useRouter()
const {
query: { data },
} = router
return <div>About us: {data}</div>
}
```